# Random numbers from different variables into one variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i console.log my code it does not show the results of the 4 variables added together it shows another random number. sorry this is hard to explain. thank you

```js
var diamonds = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
var sapphire = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
var emerald = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
var gem = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);

var results = diamonds + sapphire + emerald + gem;
console.log(results);
```

so if all 4 variables(diamonds,sapphire,emerald, and gem) equal 2. results should equal 8. but results is giving me another random number. p/s all these are in the global scale.

Comment: `diamonds` `sapphire` and others will all generate different random numbers. Please give some more expected outputs.

Comment: Your code generates 4 random numbers and then adds them together. Consider `console.log(diamonds, sapphire, emerald, gem)` to clarify whatever question you may have. Personally I'm still unclear as to your expected result.

Comment: Your code works as it is supposed to. You are generating 4 random and the sum of them is going to be a random number.

Comment: your code is already working fine check it by consoleing the diamonds ,sapphire ,emerald ,gem values seprately console.log(diamonds ,sapphire ,emerald ,gem)
console.log(results);

Comment: were you expecting them to be added like they are strings and not numbers?

Comment: I was able to figure it out thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you output the values of all the variables, then you'll see that it works:

```js
var diamonds = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
console.log('diamonds=' + diamonds)
var sapphire = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
console.log('sapphire=' + sapphire )
var emerald = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
console.log('emerald=' + emerald )
var gem = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
console.log('gem=' + gem )

var results = diamonds + sapphire + emerald + gem;
console.log('results=' + results);
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Variations of *"Your code already works"* should instead be left as *comments*, as all you're really telling OP is *"Your question can't be answered"*. (If you'd like to include a snippet in said comment, you could use an external resource like JSFiddle, Plunkr, etc.)